# What is 'p' in this grid world example given below for Q-learning and SARSA?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

This is the simple grid world problem. I am new to Machine/Reinforcement learning so I need help to understand this better. I need to implement Q-learning with epsilon-greedy action with $epsilon = 0.2, p = 0.8, alpha = 0.1$, and the grid world of size 50 by 50.
[image: What is 'p' in this and how do I implement it?]

Comment: The explanation you gave seems quite clear. This is independent of the learning algorithm you use.

Comment: @DonReba I just don't understand what does it mean when they say: These produce the expected result with a user defined probability of p and a random result with probability 1-p.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that, say if the agent wants to go up, there's 80% possibility for it to successfully reach one square above, and 20% chance to end up in somewhere else (probably because of something like, a sudden tornado in the way).

This is often represented by a probability distribution $p(s_{t+1}|s_t, a)$, where $s_t$ is the current state, $s_{t+1}$ is the next state, and $a$ the action it takes.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Is the given information enough to write python code for Q-learning and SARSA? Because, I don't understand what would be the policy from given data. The reward is + 100 for reaching goals and zero everywhere else. How should I start?

Comment: What does it mean to say 'there's 80% possibility for it to do the right thing"? Because actions would be selected randomly from: Up, Down, Right, and Left. How can it be 0.8 prob then?

Comment: @Mat_python p=0.8 is not the probability to select some action, it says if some action is selected, it has 0.8 probability to reach its expectation. for example if I want to cross the street (the action i select), I may get knocked down by a car at the pedestrian crossing, or I may get held back by someone who tries to sell me a stolen iphone. so the next state I'll end up in is not deterministic, we better model it as a probabilistic distribution.

Comment: @Mat_python actually you don't need to know the transaction model ($p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a)$) to do q-learning and sarsa, they're model-free.